# jQuery value includes any of array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I updated the question as per a helpful answer, that brought me closer, but sadly did not quite achieve what I needed.

**UPDATE:**

I am trying to create a jQuery function that will disable any checkboxes with a value that matches any part of the currently checked checkbox's value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[id^="takaritas"]').click(function() {
    if ($("#kategoria").val() == "") {
      $('input[id^="takaritas"]').prop("checked", false);
      $('input[id^="takaritas"]').val("");
      alert("Válasszon autó kategóriát!");
    } else if ($("#takaritasnincs").is(":checked")) {
      $('input[id^="takaritas"]').not(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
      $('input[id^="takaritas"]').not(this).prop("checked", false);
      $('input[id^="takaritaskoltseg"]').val("");
    } else if ($(this).not("#takaritasnincs").is(":checked")) {

      let array = $(this).val().split(" ");
      array.forEach((el, index) => {
        array[index] = array[index].replace("mosás", "").replace("Polír", "");
      });
      const filteredArray = array.filter((x) => x !== "+");
      filteredArray.forEach((el) => {

        let input = document.querySelector('[value="' + el + '"]');
        if (input) {
          document.querySelector(
            'input[type="checkbox"][value="' + el + '"]'
          ).disabled = true;
          document.querySelector(
            'input[type="checkbox"][value="' + el + '"]'
          ).checked = false;
        }
      });
    } else {
      $('input[id^="takaritas"]').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="takaritas-inline">
<input type="checkbox" id="takaritasnincs" name="takaritasnincs" value="nincs">nincs</label>
<br>

<label class='takaritas-inline'>
<input type='checkbox' name='takaritas[]' id='takaritas1' onclick='takaritasKalk(this, 0)' value='Külső mosás'>Külső mosás</label>
<br>

<label class='takaritas-inline'>
<input type='checkbox' name='takaritas[]' id='takaritas2' onclick='takaritasKalk(this, 1)' value='Belső mosás'>Belső mosás</label>
<br>


<label class='takaritas-inline'>
<input type='checkbox' name='takaritas[]' id='takaritas3' onclick='takaritasKalk(this, 2)' value='Külső + Belső mosás'>Külső + Belső mosás</label>
<br>


<label class='takaritas-inline'>
<input type='checkbox' name='takaritas[]' id='takaritas4' onclick='takaritasKalk(this, 3)' value='Külső + Belső + Wax + Motormosás'>Külső + Belső + Wax + Motormosás</label>
<br>


<label class='takaritas-inline'>
<input type='checkbox' name='takaritas[]' id='takaritas5' onclick='takaritasKalk(this, 4)' value='Polír'>Polír</label>
<br>


<label class='takaritas-inline'><input type='checkbox' name='takaritas[]' id='takaritas6' onclick='takaritasKalk(this, 5)' value='Kárpit'>Kárpit</label>
<br>


<label class='takaritas-inline'>
<input type='checkbox' name='takaritas[]' id='takaritas7' onclick='takaritasKalk(this, 6)' value='Kárpit + Wax'>Kárpit + Wax</label>
<br>


<label class='takaritas-inline'>
<input type='checkbox' name='takaritas[]' id='takaritas8' onclick='takaritasKalk(this, 7)' value='Lámpa Polír'>Lámpa Polír</label>
<br>


<label class='takaritas-inline'>
<input type='checkbox' name='takaritas[]' id='takaritas9' onclick='takaritasKalk(this, 8)' value='Komplett (polír+kárpit)'>Komplett (polír+kárpit)</label>
```

Clicking a checkbox with "Külső + Belső + Wax + Motormosás" as the value returns me this array:

```
["Külső", "+", "Belső", "+", "Wax", "+", "Motormosás"]
```

I need the function to disable any checkbox that includes any part of that array, ignoring the plus signs and the partial strings "mosás" and "polír".

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the HTML with your checkboxes?

Comment: @dave please see my updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `filter` the array then disabled it if exist like:

```js
let array = ["Külső", "+", "Belső", "+", "Wax", "+", "Motormosás"];
array.forEach((el, index) => {
  array[index] = array[index].replace('mosás', '');
});
const filteredArray = array.filter(x => x !== '+');
filteredArray.forEach(el => {
  let input = document.querySelector('[value="' + el + '"]');
  if (input) {
    input.disabled = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Wax" name="test" value="Wax">
  <label for="Wax">Wax</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Belso" name="test2" value="Belső">
  <label for="Belso">Belső</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="testvaluenodisable" name="test3" value="testvaluenodisable">
  <label for="testvaluenodisable">testvaluenodisable</label>
</div>
```

---

Edit after update:
You need to use querySelectorAll with wildcard `*=` for match all values have one element of array, then foreach that and disable it.

```js
function takaritasKalk(element, number) {
  let array = element.value.split(' ');
  array.forEach((el, index) => {
    array[index] = array[index].replace('mosás', '');
  });
  const filteredArray = array.filter(x => x !== '+');
  filteredArray.forEach(el => {
    let input = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][value*="' + el + '"]');
    if (input[0]) {
      input.forEach(inputFinal => {
        if (inputFinal.id !== element.id) {
          if (!element.checked) {
            inputFinal.disabled = false;
          } else {
            inputFinal.disabled = true;
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<label class="takaritas-inline">
<input type="checkbox" id="takaritasnincs" name="takaritasnincs" value="nincs">nincs</label>
<br>

<label class='takaritas-inline'>
<input type='checkbox' name='takaritas[]' id='takaritas1' onclick='takaritasKalk(this, 0)' value='Külső mosás'>Külső mosás</label>
<br>

<label class='takaritas-inline'>
<input type='checkbox' name='takaritas[]' id='takaritas2' onclick='takaritasKalk(this, 1)' value='Belső mosás'>Belső mosás</label>
<br>


<label class='takaritas-inline'>
<input type='checkbox' name='takaritas[]' id='takaritas3' onclick='takaritasKalk(this, 2)' value='Külső + Belső mosás'>Külső + Belső mosás</label>
<br>


<label class='takaritas-inline'>
<input type='checkbox' name='takaritas[]' id='takaritas4' onclick='takaritasKalk(this, 3)' value='Külső + Belső + Wax + Motormosás'>Külső + Belső + Wax + Motormosás</label>
<br>


<label class='takaritas-inline'>
<input type='checkbox' name='takaritas[]' id='takaritas5' onclick='takaritasKalk(this, 4)' value='Polír'>Polír</label>
<br>


<label class='takaritas-inline'><input type='checkbox' name='takaritas[]' id='takaritas6' onclick='takaritasKalk(this, 5)' value='Kárpit'>Kárpit</label>
<br>


<label class='takaritas-inline'>
<input type='checkbox' name='takaritas[]' id='takaritas7' onclick='takaritasKalk(this, 6)' value='Kárpit + Wax'>Kárpit + Wax</label>
<br>


<label class='takaritas-inline'>
<input type='checkbox' name='takaritas[]' id='takaritas8' onclick='takaritasKalk(this, 7)' value='Lámpa Polír'>Lámpa Polír</label>
<br>


<label class='takaritas-inline'>
<input type='checkbox' name='takaritas[]' id='takaritas9' onclick='takaritasKalk(this, 8)' value='Komplett (polír+kárpit)'>Komplett (polír+kárpit)</label>
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer, it brought me closer to what I am trying to achieve, but sadly it didn't fully fix the issue. +1 nevertheless.

Comment: Which is the problem :)?

Comment: Please see my question updated with your answer. As you can see in the code snippet, clicking "Belső mosás" won't disable the two below it, or vice versa.

Comment: See my update..

Comment: I wish I could give you another +1. It is almost perfect. Now the only issue is that it also disables the one I click (I should be able to uncheck the box and return to everything being clickable)

Comment: Wait so the first array i used is the value of clicked checkbox?

Comment: yes, it is the value of a checkbox split into an array

Comment: Done, now take value from input you checked and disable others containe the same value, if you uncheck it script will active all.